# Planetary Clouds

Tags: volumetrics

Is it possible to create a planetary-volumetric style clouds on the faces of a sphere? Every attempt I try always comes out to look too 2d when approaching the image closely. I tried the volume output but as it says, it only keeps the stuff inside the circle and looks oddly flat on the top. If there is anything you can think of that would help thanks.

[image]

Comment: You need to generate a point volume that respects the boundaries of the mesh, the top surface and the interior world surface. Blenders volume nodes don't have this attribute. Sorry

Comment: To be clear, you *can* use a point density cloud but its hard to generate in the detail you need.

Comment: I’ll try that and see if it will work, thanks for he help. 

Comment: The answer to this question may help - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111462/planetary-atmospheric-volumetric-clouds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Planetary/Atmospheric volumetric clouds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111462/planetary-atmospheric-volumetric-clouds)